# How to add extension to url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this url `<?php echo esc_url($edit_link);?>` but I need to add the extension in the end of url  `"&tab=calendar"` to point the user to correct tab.

I can't use full url I need to add to this `$edit_link` the extension off `&tab=calendar`

How can I do that?

Comment: `$edit_link.'&tab=calendar'`?

Comment: What @AksenP said, or if you have multiple params use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php and then append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple concatenating a string  -> `$edit_link.'&tab=calendar'`:

```
<?php echo esc_url($edit_link.'&tab=calendar');?>
```